# Get the index of a specific class repeated on the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML I have a div that is repeated, it is something like this:-

```
<div class="col-md-3 SeccaoProduto">
   <p class="productName"></p>
   <p>Quantidade Atual: <span class="quantidadeProduto"></span></p>
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs IncrementaProduto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></button>
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs DecrementaProduto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></button>
</div>
```

When I click the button that has the DecrementaProduto class, I want to get the specific index of that class, in this case DecrementaProduto is the first time that it appears on my html, I want the index = 0;

**In my JavaScript I tried this:-**

```
$(".DecrementaProduto").click(function(){
   console.log($(".SeccaoProduto").index(this));
});
```

But I always get the value = -1 :S
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$(this)` refers to the clicked button but the collection does not include the button so the returned value would be `-1`.

Instead, you need to get the parent element `.DecrementaProduto` which contains the clicked element. Where you can use the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get the element.

```
$(".DecrementaProduto").click(function(){
   console.log($(".SeccaoProduto").index($(this).parent()));
   //                                ------------^^^^^^^---
});
```